# Migrate from LXC to LXD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, server, lxc

I have installed LXC(Linux Containers) on Ubuntu Server 14.4 Host and i have some virtual servers running on it,but now i want to migrate all these containers to LXD, i have worked so hard configuring these containers and i don't want to lose all of these configurations. 
This is my sketch:

```
                                     HOST
                              Ubuntu Server LXC

             Container             Container           Container
             Ubuntu 12             Ubuntu 12             CentOS
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about: http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/lxd I think it's very early to start with it.
I have started to follow this project with first initial commit 3 month before. **There wasn't release yet.**

PS:

Getting started with LXD

Our OpenStack container capability, codenamed nova-compute-flex is included in Ubuntu OpenStack for Juno, which you can download via the Ubuntu Cloud Archive. Simply type the following commands to enable and use it:

sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:juno

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nova-compute-flex

OpenStack Juno is available for Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and 14.10.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in [migrating lxc to lxd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377916/migrating-lxc-to-lxd?s=1|3.6480), you can do so by creating a dummy LXD container and replacing its rootfs, then updating some of the config to match your LXC container's configuration.

Specifically, if your source container was privileged, you'll want to set security.privileged=true at least until such time as you have confirmed your workload works properly unprivileged (just set security.privileged=false and restart the container with "lxc restart").