# migrating lxc to lxd

Tags: migration, lxc, lxd

I've looked all over, but can't see if there is a way.  I have a couple LXC containers running Ubuntu 14.04 on top of a Ubuntu 14.04 Host.  They've become pretty important to me, so I want to be able to easily backup / migrate the LXC containers to another server if the host's hardware should fail.

I've built a new Ubuntu 15.1 server now with LXD and have logged out and back in and see the new group.  For testing, I tar'd one of my existing LXC containers up with the `--numeric-owner` switch on my 14.04 Host:

`tar --numeric-owner -czvf ContToBeMoved.tgz /var/lib/lxc/my_container`

---then on new server ---

`tar --numeric-owner -xzvf ContToBeMoved.tgz -C /var/lib/lxc/`

...and have successfully restored the LXC container on the new server 15.1 server.

When I run the LXD commands though, LXD doesn't see the container.  I tried moving the container to the `/var/lib/lxd/containers` directory and still, LXD doesn't see it.  Is there a way to edit / clone / migrate the LXC container so that we can use LXD moving forward?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

LXD uses a sqlite database for container configuration so just dumping the container's rootfs in place won't be quite enough.

The easiest way to do what you want is to create a new container with LXD, then remove its rootfs from /var/lib/lxd/containers/NAME/rootfs and substitute the one from your original host.

Note that LXD runs unprivileged containers by default, if your source container was privileged (/var/lib/lxc/NAME/rootfs is owned by root:root instead of 100000:100000), then you'll want to run the following too:

```
lxc config set NAME security.privileged true
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback, and your info makes perfect sense.  I'll give it a shot as soon as I'm able to.  Right now have configured a backup LXC server, but live migration with LXD is just too impressive to pass up! =)  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this useful answer, however, this seems to not take into account the IPv4 network configuration, probably exactly because only the rootfs contents are copied over..

I just stumbled upon the https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/scripts/lxc-to-lxd script, but that also doesn't seem to like the `lxc.network.ipv4` configuration key(s)?