# How to setup permissions on migrated lxc->lxd container?

Tags: lxc, lxd

@stgraber said that we need to replace rootfs to migrate from lxc to lxd container:

[migrating lxc to lxd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377916/migrating-lxc-to-lxd)

How to setup permissions on files and folders of migrated container if I want to make the container unprivileged, like some existing pure-lxd containers.

For example, existing pure-lxd container permissions (from host):

```
root@ubuntu1404:/var/lib/lxd# ll containers/trusty/rootfs/home/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 493216 493216  12 Apr 29 06:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 493216 493216 132 Apr 29 06:55 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 494216 494216  54 Apr 29 06:57 ubuntu/
```

Is there an easy way to do this ?